# Problem with the bake result, how can I fix it?

Tags: materials, uv, texture-baking, shader-nodes

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong, but I haven't been able to do a simple Bake for a day. In this example I have 2 materials on the same object. I mapped with UV mapping, copied the object, and applied the material to the copied object, making the copied object diffuse the bake result of the first object.

Obviously I inserted a "Bake Diffuse" image in all 2 materials on which I have to bake with the relative selected nodes, as per practice.

The result I get, however, is strange.

I am using Blender 3.0.1

I leave the original file for sharing here:
[Bake Test.blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eyKAUBWPYGbbcNFnJIAYTb5jEPeeGLNG/view?usp=sharing)[image]

Answer (score 1):

Look at your UVs for the object that is supposed to receive the bake, the faces are overlapping, so what happens is that the bake for a face appears on another face. What you need to do is unwrap your object again, for example with the *Smart UV Project* mode.

[image]